# how to check whether string inserted to arangodb collection is already present in the collection or not?

Tags: python-3.x, arangodb

while inputing a question,I want to check whether it is in the collection or not.if it is in the collection return the equation and result.following is json code of my collection example.

```
[
    {
        "_key":"292305",
        "_id":"example/292305",
        "_rev":"_UcMLNR6---",
        "Equation":"3+2",
        "Question":"Reece has 3 fish. He wants to get 2 more fish. How many fish would he have then?",
        "result":5
    },
    {
        "_key":"292490",
        "_id":"example/292490",
        "_rev":"_UcMM3XO---","Equation":"6+3","Question":"Luke has 6 cars. He buys 3 more cars. How many cars does Luke have now?",
        "Result":9
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
question=(request.form['question'])
  db= client.db('my_db')
  jru = db.collection('jru')
  result = db.aql.execute('FOR u in jru FILTER u.Question==@question RETURN  u',bind_vars={'question':question})
return render_template("o.html",result=result)
```